# Selenium C#: string contains

Tags: c#, string

I have something like:

```
string result = Selenium.GetText("/html/body/form/div[2]");
if (result.Contains("test")
{
   bool found = true;
}
else
{
   found = false;
}
```

My problem is using `result.Contains()` returns false if there are tests, testing, etc. Also returns false for uppercase TEST, Test, etc

Is there another method that would match each character? Something like: `result.Match("test");`

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: result.Contains("test") will return true if result contains "tests" or "testing" because each of the words contains "test".

Comment: @ Wesley Wiser: really? I did not think so. Let me try again.

Comment: `result.Contains("test")` will return true if "test" occurs anywhere in `result`, regardless of whether it's a whole or partial word. If it returns false, then "test" doesn't occur anywhere in result. But note that this is a case-sensitive search. Are you sure the case matches?

Comment: @ Charles: Thanks, I tried again, and figured that it was a case issue. I used ToUpper, and it is returning true. Thanks again Wesley and Charles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon my awful code, though it works:

```
var aStartsWithB = stringA.ToUpper().StartsWith(stringB.ToUpper());
var aContainsB = stringA.ToUpper().Contains(stringB.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 2):

`string.StartsWith` is a good start, and then `Regex` if you need more power

Comment: Regex is the fastest way to do a proper check + it's very flexible - it might be hard to grasp.

Comment: @Rogier21 fastest in what sense? `StartsWith` is quicker.

Comment: Probably it is, but it's not contains :) Compiled regex' are usually very fast, faster than most compare functions.

Answer (score 1):

contains it should work fine:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string result = @"/html/body/form/tests123456";
    var containsTest= result.Contains("test"); // <--True
}
```

Just bear in mind that Contains is case sensitive

You could use a version of string.Contains case insensitive as showed on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) below.